# Get the rows of the max attribute from a subquery made in FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT pname, devcost
FROM (
         SELECT P.pname, budget / COUNT(*) as devcost
         FROM project P,
              devassignments D
         WHERE P.pname = D.pname
         GROUP BY P.pname) as t
WHERE devcost = (SELECT MAX(devcost)
                 FROM t)
ORDER BY pname
;
```

In the SQL query above, I want to get rows that correspond to the max devcost of the table t. However, when I run this I get an error

```
ERROR: relation "t" does not exist
```

What's the best way to go about this? And on a side-note, what's the point of defining alias `t` if I can't reference it later on in the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions . . . and proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT pname, devcost
FROM (SELECT P.pname, budget / COUNT(*) as devcost,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY budget / COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM project P JOIN
           devassignments D
           ON P.pname = D.pname
      GROUP BY P.pname
     ) n
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY pname
```